# Chang backgroundImage with onmouseover and onmouseout in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change backgroundImage with the following code: document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = ?

```
#image{
    line-height:650px;
        width: 575px;
    height: 650px;
        border:5px solid black;
        margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #8e68ff;
    background-image: url('');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    font-size: 150%;
}
.preview{
        width:10%;
        margin-left:17%;
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id = "image">
        Hover over an image below to display here.
    </div>
    
    <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
    
    <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
    
    <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
```

Comment: Do you want mouseout and mouseover to change the background? Or only after both events have occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it like this, without changing your HTML structure.

By the way, just like `unDo()` function, you don't have to pass `this` as argument. You can use this, directly in function.

Cheers!

```js
var image = document.getElementById('image');

function upDate(imageHover) {
  let currentSrc = imageHover.getAttribute("src");
  image.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + currentSrc + "')";
}

function unDo() {
  image.style.backgroundImage = "";
}
```

```css
#image {
  line-height: 650px;
  width: 575px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #8e68ff;
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.preview {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
```

Comment: Don't worry, I did not write my code after reading yours. I interpreted question incorrectly earlier, and hence, deleted my answer, corrected it, and un-deleted it.

Comment: Thanks, Pranav. Your answer is the one I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get the `src` of currently `mouseover` img and apply it your `div` with `image` inside it. You need to have `img` inside your `div` so that we can use that div to hide `img` on `mouseout`

Use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method to get the element which will be `#preview` img which we have inside the div `#image`

Use `.style.display` in your `unDo()` function to hide the image on `mouseover` so that the div can go back to its `original` state.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
let imgPreview = document.querySelector('#preview')

//mouseover
function upDate(event) {
  let getSrc = event.getAttribute('src')
  imgPreview.style.display = 'block' //show div
  imgPreview.src = getSrc //replace src
}
 
//mouse out
function unDo() {
  imgPreview.style.display = 'none' //hide div
}
```

```css
#image {
  line-height: 650px;
  width: 575px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #8e68ff;
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.preview {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <img src="" id="preview" /> Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still don't understand with your "Undo" means, may be like this one, may help for you :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 
    <style>

      #image{ 
      line-height:650px; 
      width: 575px; height: 650px; 
      border:5px solid black; 
      margin:0 auto; 
      background-color: #8e68ff; 
      background-image: url(''); 
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      color:#FFFFFF; text-align: center; 
      background-size: 100%; 
      margin-bottom:25px; 
      font-size: 150%; 
      } 
      
      .preview{ 
      width:10%; 
      margin-left:17%; 
      border: 10px solid black; 
      }
      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

       <div id = "image"> Hover over an image below to display here. </div> 
       
             <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this.src)" onmouseout = "unDo()"> 

             <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this.src)" onmouseout = "unDo()"> 

             <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this.src)" onmouseout = "unDo()">



 

    <script>
         // update mouseover
      function upDate(clicked_src) { 
        document.getElementById("image").style.background = "url( ' "+clicked_src+" ')" ;
      }

      function unDo() {
        document.getElementById("image").style.background = "" ;

       
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```